# Scatter Plot of Binned Data using Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, plot, data-binding

I am trying to bin data according to the modulus of a Q vector and add up all of the intensities that fall within bins along the mod(Q) axis. I am then trying to plot a scatter graph of the binned intensities with the position along the mod(Q) axis being the centre of the bins.

I've taken in the data from an external file and put it into a pandas dataframe. I've then added another column to this pandas dataframe to give the value of mod(Q).

Next, I created bins for my data. These bins were created using "cut" from pandas. I then made a grouped pandas dataframe with the bins and the sum of the intensities that fall within these bins. I am struggling however to use this grouped pandas dataframe to produce a scatter plot.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import style

raw_data_file_path = '../Raw_Data_Files/Original_Files/constantEcutsModified'

df = pd.read_csv(raw_data_file_path, sep=',', header=None, names=['Q_1', 'Q_2', 'intensity', 'uncertainty'])

df['mod_Q'] = np.sqrt(df['Q_1']**2 + df['Q_2']**2)

bins = pd.cut(df['mod_Q'], 100)
grouped_df = df.groupby(bins)['intensity'].agg('sum')
```

This is what I get from printing the top 15 rows of grouped_df:

```py
mod_Q
(-0.014, 0.14]        0.0000
(0.14, 0.28]          0.0000
(0.28, 0.421]         0.0000
(0.421, 0.561]        0.0000
(0.561, 0.701]        0.0000
(0.701, 0.841]        0.0000
(0.841, 0.982]        0.0000
(0.982, 1.122]     6979.8172
(1.122, 1.262]     9873.2400
(1.262, 1.402]    17253.2000
(1.402, 1.543]    22006.3200
(1.543, 1.683]    24311.7400
(1.683, 1.823]    28123.0800
(1.823, 1.963]    29002.4300
(1.963, 2.104]    34473.0770
Name: intensity, dtype: float64
```

Comment: pandas has a built in plot function that you can use with groupby objects. I also recommend taking a look at seaborn if you're plotting data from pandas dataframes. Seaborn is a package built around matplotlib that makes generating plots from pandas dataframes easier. Can you provide an example of your dataframe?

Comment: @iamchoosinganame I've just edited the post to include what I get when I print out some of the rows. The first issue I have is that I'm not sure that the variable "grouped_df" is in fact a dataframe. Do you know whether it is?

Comment: yes, it is, you can try `type(grouped_df)` to get any variable's type.

Comment: as iamchoosinganame said, try seaborn, for example
`import seaborn as sns

sns.distplot(df['mod_Q'])
`